# Как узнать, с какого сайта к нам пришел пользователь?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт, который бы показывал, с какого сайта к нам пришел юзер. Если он же просто ввел в адресной строке адрес, то перенести его на главную страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Спасибки =)

Comment: Переадресацию можно сделать так:

header("Location: http://www.example.com/");

Comment: С переадресацией могут быть проблемы, если до заголовка т.е до 
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); будет какая-нибудь команда вывода(например: echo "test text";).Это на заметку Вам.

Comment: я так сделал:
<?php 
$block = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(strln($block)>0){
//Код страницы
}
else{
echo "<script>location.href='/index.php';</script>";
}

Comment: Если у меня отключен javascript, то ваш код не сработает.Всё же лучше через заголовок.